How many people for kiddush Levana
How many people should one say kiddush levana with? Is this a must or is it preferable?

https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/may-kiddush-levana-be-recited-if-one-is-alone/#:~:text=The%20Beiur%20Halacha%20(426%2C%20s.v.,(Mishlei%2014%3A28).

What do other people have to do with kiddush levana? Do you also make sure to say birkas hatorah with other people? I don't understand. No rishon mentions such a thing as far as I know, nor is it in Shulchan Aruch TTBOMK

@DoubleAA ברכת הלבנה, in many communities, is usually recited by an entire Minyan after ערבית. Considering such a context, this question has a good basis.

@Qwerty those at shul usually recite it with the shul and those at home usually recite it at home. Not sure what special pattern you're seeing

@DoubleAA Most people go to מִניָנים regularly enough to say ברכת הלבנה with them. In communities where such is the established norm, one may go most of his life without saying it alone, and such a question might arise.

@DoubleAA who you going to say Shalom Aleichem to if you’re not with people?

@Qwerty that's not true, maybe most people at your shul, but not most people overall. In any event that's about as compelling a reasoning as "Can you do hatarat nedarim outside of a shul" since most Jews have only ever done that there. Or even "Can you count Omer alone" since everyone goes to minyan counts there.

@rosends will you create an answer?

@Yoreinu I don't think the halacha answers all the relevant questions. If one says it alone, how does one do the shalom aleichem part? (is that an integral part or not).

@rosends Shalom aleichem is not necessary when one says KL alone. You only say it in order to show to people around you that you didn't mean them when you said תפול אליהם אימתה ופחד. So if there are no people around no Shalom aleichem is required

@Yoreinu that's helpful, but the question isn't asking just about the need for a minyan. -- it is asking a more general question about numbers. If the answer is "one may say it alone" then no other answer is needed. But if there is a preference to say it with 4, 6 or 10 or more, then that needs a source.

@Yoreinu Even if you decide some larger group is preferable, the question remains how preferable. What if the only group is: not after dark? not on Saturday night? Not on 10 Av? Not before/after 3/7 days (depending which of the 4 permutations you hold is best)? What if you would lose Zrizin Makdimin? What if you have a group of X now but later you'll have a group of 2*X? Etc. Not to mention the hassle component, which is why you probably aren't careful to say Birkat Hatorah with a large crowd.

@rosends what am i missing, your article cites the biur halacha, based on that  one can do it alone but it's better to do it berov am. how much berov am is is an argument between the chayei adam and MB, 3 or 10 repsectiely
